# How does that syntax for defining a full function template specialization a friend of a class?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend-function

I saw the following example at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) (" Template friend operators" section), simplified

```cpp
template<typename> struct Foo;
template<typename T> void bar(Foo<T>) {}

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    // friend void bar<T>(Foo f);  // (1)
    friend void bar<>(Foo f);  // (2)
};

int main() {
    bar(Foo<int>{});
}
```

Here either `(1)` or `(2)` work equally well. I understand that in `(1)` compiler says that one specific instantiation of `bar` (namely, `bar<T>` with such-and-such parameters) is a friend of `Foo<T>`, but I do not understand what happens in `(2)`.

What type parameters does compiler use for `bar` in `(2)`? How does that work in general? How is that syntax called, is it defined somewhere in the Standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See C++17 [temp.friend]/1:

> A friend of a class or class template can be a function template or class template, a specialization of a function template or class template, or a non-template function or class. For a friend function declaration that is not a template declaration:
>
> - if the name of the friend is a qualified or unqualified *template-id*, the friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template, otherwise,
> - if the name of the friend is a *qualified-id* and a matching non-template function is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to that function, otherwise,
> - if the name of the friend is a *qualified-id* and a matching function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to the deduced specialization of that function template (17.8.2.6), otherwise,
> - the name shall be an *unqualified-id* that declares (or redeclares) a non-template function.

The names `bar<T>` and `bar<>` are both *template-id*s, so if you use either one, then it refers to a specialization of the function template `::bar`. As specified in [temp.arg.explicit]:

> Template arguments can be specified when referring to a function template specialization by qualifying the function template name with the list of *template-arguments* ... A template argument list may be specified when referring to a specialization of a function template ... in a friend declaration. Trailing template arguments that can be deduced (17.8.2) or obtained from default *template-arguments* may be omitted from the list of explicit *template-arguments*. ... If all of the template arguments can be deduced, they may all be omitted; ...

Thus, the meaning of `bar<>` in the friend declaration is that template argument deduction shall be done to determine which specialization of `bar` is being referred to. Of course, the deduced specialization is the one that takes an argument of the type `Foo<T>`. So the two declarations with `bar<>` and `bar<T>` would have the same meaning.